# "425 Can't open data connection" only from some clients

Tags: windows-7, ftp, filezilla

I have several Windows 7 computers on the same network using the same router. On one of them I installed FileZilla server.

Using Chrome, Internet Explorer, etc. I am able to connect and upload to the server from all client computers.

I also have a .NET program that uploads files using `FtpWebRequest` class. When I try to upload using my program it works from some computers but not from others. I get the following error from the server:

> 425 Can’t open data connection for transfer of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a problem of firewalls blocking data connections into the computer. You need to switch to passive mode, see [Is it possible to use “Passive Mode” with FtpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530811/is-it-possible-to-use-passive-mode-with-ftpwebrequest).